# Obtener valor GET de mi URL javascript

Tags: javascript

```
/index.php/view/corte/8
```

necesito sacar a ese `8` de la ecuacion pero como podria hacer con Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener la `URL` y el ultimo valor de la misma puedes utilizar el método `split` de la siguiente manera:

```
function getUrl(){
     //Se obtiene el valor de la URL desde el navegador
     var actual = window.location+'';
     //Se realiza la división de la URL
     var split = actual.split("/");
     //Se obtiene el ultimo valor de la URL
     var id = split[split.length-1];
     console.log(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes lograr esto usando el objeto [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) que es parte del objeto global `window` y realizando un poco the manipulación de strings:

```
let paths = window.location.pathname.split('/');
let id = paths[paths.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando javascript, puede usar el siguiente código "*suponiendo que la última posición de la URL sea el valor que quieres obtener*":

```js
// Esta es la url que pones de ejemplo:
var mi_url = "/index.php/view/corte/8";

// En este arreglo guardaremos la URL "separada por la barra diagonal":
var arreglo_datos = mi_url.split('/');

// En una variable separada almacenamos el valor que se encuentra al final de la URL.
var valor_a_obtener = arreglo_datos[arreglo_datos.length - 1];

// Imprimimos el valor obtenido "tanto en el control de tipo (span) como en la consola.
document.getElementById('spn_resultado').innerHTML = valor_a_obtener;
console.log(valor_a_obtener);
```

```html
El resultado es: <span id="spn_resultado" />
```